# Returning .empty Observable inside .switchMap operator

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I think I've found a bug in the RxJS library or just can't understand it's behavior. Take a look at the following code:

```js
const { Observable, Subject } = Rx;

const source$ = new Subject();

const handle = v => {
  if (v === 0) {
    source$.next(1);
    return Observable.empty();
  }  
  return Observable.interval(1000).startWith(-1).take(3);
}

source$
  .do(e => console.log('source:', e))
  // .delay(1)
  // .switchMap(v => Observable.of(null).switchMap(() => handle(v)))
  .switchMap(v => handle(v))
  .subscribe(e => console.log('handle:', e))

source$.next(0); // <- initial value
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

**Working scenario:** When I run it with `source$.next(1)`, I see the following result(which is correct):

```
source: 1
handle: -1
handle: 0
handle: 1
```

**Broken scenario:** When I run it with `source$.next(0)`, I expect to see:

```
source: 0
... (exactly the same output as for the previous example)
```

But instead I see only 3 values:

```
source: 0
source: 1
handle: -1
```

**Workaround 1:** When I put `.delay(1)` as you can see in the comments - it works fine, just as I have expected. I think this is because default Scheduler executed synchronously in the same tick vs using async Scheduler when using delay.

**Question**
When I use `Observable.of(null)` (see comments in the code) it gives me the same("correct" or expected) result too. Why is that? Shouldn't it be the same synchronous as before?

Comment: This is pretty edge case, another workaround is to `.empty().finally`: http://plnkr.co/edit/cdmm9N3c0u4ZEHpOXaMc?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is correct. It's the synchronous emission from the `source` that makes it a little weird.

Emitting `1` from within the `handle` method effects a re-enterant call that sees the `startWith` value of `-1` emitted *before* the `Observable.empty` is returned - as the `startWith` value is emitted synchronously.

That means that the `switchMap` sees the `startWith`/`interval` observable first and the `empty` observable second. It then switches to the `empty` observable, effecting the output that you see.

Adding a `delay` prevents the re-enterant call.

Comment: Hmm I am not quite convinced by this explanation - for me it looks like a bug. Once `switchMap` switched to the next stream, the previous stream should get unsubscribed and its emissions ignored.

Comment: At first, I've had the same thoughts about this. But `.switchMap` works fine, exactly as you have described. Take a closer look: `source$.next(1)` is executed **before** the `.empty()` gets returned. In other words `.empty` is the second and `interval` is first.

Comment: Played a bit more with it today and now it makes sense to me. Thank you and sorry for introducing unnecessary confussion.

Comment: "Adding a delay prevents the re-enterant call." 

I think this statement is incorrect. The `delay` causes `empty()` observable to preempt `interval()` observable, so `switchmap()` discards the former and executes the latter